# Insert multiple blanks every n rows

Tags: bash, awk, blank-line

I am trying to insert multiple blank lines after every n row in a data file.

So far I have this line which inserts 1 blank line after every 1 row:

```
awk '1 ; !(NR % 1) {print "";}' in.file >> out.file
```

And then I try to loop it so I insert 10 lines every 1 row:

```
awk '1; {for(i=0; i<10; i++)} !(NR % 1) {print "";}'
```

But I don't think I have the syntax correct. Any suggestions?

Ideal output would be to take take input-A and paste it to input-B so that it looks like this:

(1) input-A

```
>1   
>0   
>1
```

(2) input-B

```
>1000    
>... ... ...  
>... ... ...  
>... ... ...  
>2000    
>... ... ...  
>... ... ...  
>... ... ...  
>3000    
>... ... ...  
>... ... ...  
>... ... ...
```

(3) pasted input-A and input-B

```
>1  1000    
>   ... ... ...  
>   ... ... ...  
>   ... ... ...  
>0  2000    
>   ... ... ...  
>   ... ... ...  
>   ... ... ...  
>1  3000    
>   ... ... ...  
>   ... ... ...  
>   ... ... ...
```

Hence why I'm trying to create the right amount of spaces between the lines of input-A so that it easily pastes with input-B.

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing what you have tried to solve this problem, please do add samples of input and output too in your post to make it more clearer, cheers.

Comment: You almost certainly are approaching this wrong but without know what those `...`s in input-B actually represent and how they differ from the numbered lines in that same file we can't help you create a robust tool to do the job in a better way. As rule don't put `.`s in your sample input/output, put actual representative text as that's far more helpful to us trying to understand your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert 2 blank lines every 3 input lines:

```
$ seq 10 |
    awk -v n=2 -v m=3 '
        BEGIN {
            lines = sprintf("%*s",n-1,"")
            gsub(/ /,ORS,lines)
        }
        { print }
        (NR%m) == 0 {
            print lines
        }
    '
1
2
3


4
5
6


7
8
9


10
```

To print 12,000 blank lines every 10 input lines instead, just change n=2 to n=12000 and m=3 to m=10.

If that's not what you want then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide concise, testable sample input and expected output.

wrt your updated question, depending on what those `...`s in inputB are, this might be what you really should be using:

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { a[NR]=$0; next }
    {
        sub(/^>/,"")
        print (NF==1 ? a[++c] : ">") OFS $0
    }
' inputA inputB
>1 1000
> ... ... ...
> ... ... ...
> ... ... ...
>0 2000
> ... ... ...
> ... ... ...
> ... ... ...
>1 3000
> ... ... ...
> ... ... ...
> ... ... ...
```

Comment: 1 question sir, is there any limit for `%s*` here? or we could give any number in it to print spaces and then convert them to new lines.

Comment: There probably is some limit on how long a string can be but 12000 characters won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT2:*** Your question drastically changed from 1 to another, never mind could you please try following for your 2 files question.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next} NF==1{sub(/^>/,"");print a[++count],$0;next} 1' inputa inputb
```

---

***EDIT:*** Since OP mentioned in comments OP wants to inject 12,000 lines after every 10th line of Input_file. Ok, so here is the deal I could write a loop which will each time iterate 12,000 times in code to print the blank lines and make the code's processing very very slow for huge files. I have come up with something like create a file which has 12,000 BLANK lines in it first and then in `awk` code simply call it to print lines which will be much much faster than approach of printing 12,000 lines each time in a loop.

***1st Step:*** Create a file with 12,000 blank lines as follows.

```
awk 'BEGIN{while(++i<=12000){print "" > "blank_file"}}'
```

***2nd step:*** Checking the lines are 12,000 in file.

```
wc -l "blank_file"
12000 blank_file
```

***3rd step:*** Make actual code to print 12000 blank line each time in your real code.

```
awk 'FNR%10==0{print;system("cat blank_file");next} 1'  Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** In 2nd step you could change `12000` to number of blank lines in that loop and could print more or less lines too.

---

---

Let's say you want to insert 3 new lines after every 10 lines of Input_file if this is the case then following may help you here.

```
awk 'FNR%10==0{print $0 ORS ORS ORS;next} 1' Input_file
```

If you want to take output into output_file then append `> output_file` to above code too.

Comment: thank you, I found some other solutions that had something similar but I have to insert 12,000 lines and am trying to find a way to not write out ORS every time. I might just be going about this the wrong way.

Comment: @simod, you haven't tell how many times you have to insert a blank line, let me check now.

Comment: @simod, I could write a loop but problem is it will run 12000 times then and your processing may be slow then.

Comment: @simod, see my EDIT code now, it should print 12000 lines after every 10 lines of your actual file without any loop or so, let me know if this helps you?

Comment: thank you for the quick feedback! I will check both of them out right now.

Comment: @simod, I just now saw you had changed your basic question itself, I added EDIT2 solution for same too now.